# Full Width Horizontal Centered Menu and Sub Menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to create a menu with a sub menu. I would like both menus to be horizontal, full width and centered. Is this possible and, if so, does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

This code creates a horizontal menu and sub menu however they are left aligned and I cannot get them both full width and both centered.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 4 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 4 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 4 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>  
</ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#menu {
  width: 960px;
  height: 40px;
  clear: both;
}

ul#nav {
  float: left;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #dc0000 url(../img/menu-parent.png) repeat-x;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;  
  text-align: center;
}

ul#nav li {
  display: inline;
}

ul#nav li a {
  float: left;
  font: bold 1.1em arial,verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #880000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background: #dc0000 url(../img/menu-parent.png) repeat-x;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;     
}

/* APPLIES THE ACTIVE STATE */
ul#nav .current a, ul#nav li:hover > a  {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #330000;
  background: #bb0000;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
}

/* THE SUBMENU LIST HIDDEN BY DEFAULT */
ul#nav  ul {
  display: none;
}

/* WHEN THE FIRST LEVEL MENU ITEM IS HOVERED, THE CHILD MENU APPEARS */
 /* Sub menu UL */
ul#nav li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 920px;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  background: #aa0000 url(../img/menu-child.png) repeat-x;  
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; 
}

 /* Sub menu link */
ul#nav li:hover > ul li a {
  float: left;
  font: bold 1.1em arial,verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #110000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  background: #aa0000 url(../img/menu-child.png) repeat-x; 
}

  /* Sub menu link hover */
ul#nav li:hover > ul li a:hover {
  color: #120000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
  </style>
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Show us some of your code.

Comment: Apologies. I have edited my original post with code that I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKLhy)

I have used `display: table;` for the `UL` and `display: table-cell` for the `li` for making the menu adjust.

HTML

```
<div id="menu">

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
 <div class="dropdown"><ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
<div class="dropdown"> <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
 <div class="dropdown"><ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 4 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 4 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 4 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
</li>  
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
  width: 960px;
  height: 40px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}

ul#nav {
  display: table;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #dc0000 url(../img/menu-parent.png) repeat-x;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;  
  text-align: center;
}

ul#nav li {
  display: table-cell;
}

ul#nav li a {
  display: block;
  font: bold 1.1em arial,verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #880000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background: #dc0000 url(../img/menu-parent.png) repeat-x;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;     
}

/* APPLIES THE ACTIVE STATE */
ul#nav .current a, ul#nav li:hover > a  {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #330000;
  background: #bb0000;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
}

/* THE SUBMENU LIST HIDDEN BY DEFAULT */
ul#nav  .dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
ul#nav  .dropdown ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* WHEN THE FIRST LEVEL MENU ITEM IS HOVERED, THE CHILD MENU APPEARS */
 /* Sub menu UL */
ul#nav li:hover > .dropdown {

  display: block;

  background: #aa0000 url(../img/menu-child.png) repeat-x;  
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; 
}
ul#nav li > .dropdown a {
  padding: 3px 30px
}
 /* Sub menu link */
ul#nav li:hover > ul li a {
  font: bold 1.1em arial,verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #110000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  background: #aa0000 url(../img/menu-child.png) repeat-x; 
}

  /* Sub menu link hover */
ul#nav li:hover > ul li a:hover {
  color: #120000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```